# how solve bad request error after uploading excel files using spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have got this error:

> Type Status Report
>
> Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to
>   something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed
>   request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).

here is my controller and I am working for uploading multiple excel files:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UploadFileController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "uploadFile.do", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ModelAndView uploadFile(@ModelAttribute("uploadForm") UploadFile uploadForm, Model map,BindingResult bindingResult) throws org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException{

        ArrayList<UploadFile> uploadFileList = new ArrayList<UploadFile>();
        List<File> files = uploadForm.getFiles();
         for(File excelFile : files){
                try {

                    ((MultipartFile) excelFile).transferTo(new File(((MultipartFile) excelFile).getOriginalFilename()));
                    uploadFileList  = ReadFile.readFile(excelFile);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                }
            }

         return new ModelAndView("redirect","uploadFileList",uploadFileList);

    }
```

can someone should help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is due to below codes,you have invoke `transferTo()`method,after that,you can not read the file again.

```
  ((MultipartFile) excelFile).transferTo(new File(((MultipartFile) excelFile).getOriginalFilename()));
  uploadFileList  = ReadFile.readFile(excelFile);//you can not read the file again
```